# How can I allow multiple file selection in an Alfresco file browse window?

Tags: alfresco

How can I allow multiple file selection in an Alfresco file browse window?
Currently when a user clicks on the "browse" button, the file browse
window is displayed and the user can only select one file.
Is it possible to allow multiple file selection?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you using? Is it Alfresco Share? Which browser?

Comment: Alfresco version 3.3, yes it is Share. I use Chrome, but it needs to work for all (or at least IE & FF)

Comment: Can you upgrade? Newer versions of Share do have some multi-select options

Comment: Do you use Flash upload? Also, in which form/dashlet - something custom? Because you can set file upload mode to MODE_UPLOAD_SINGLE or MODE_UPLOAD_MULTI, or something similar in upload config.

Comment: Not using flash upload. Where is the upload config done?

Answer (score 0):

For som reason you are not getting the flash uploader to show up. Either it has been disabled in your installation or you dont have the correct flash version installed. In later versions there are drag and drop support. However since Microsoft dont implement all html5 this does not work on ie browsers.